# Extending Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, class, backbone.js, prototype

I'm trying to extend my Backbone.View class. 
Initially i come up with the idea of creating my own interface to simplify the amount of code required to remove childViews.

Basically, an array and some methods to iterate over each view on the array calling remove for each one. This is specially useful on lists and things like that.

Then i tried something similar to this and realize that Objects create from the class were sharing the same instance on their properties.

```
Backbone.SuperView = Backbone.View.extend({
  childViews: ['global']
})


var App_View = Backbone.SuperView.extend({
   initialize: function(options){
       this.childViews.push(options.viewName);
console.log('app_View =>' + this.childViews);
   }
})

var App2_View = Backbone.SuperView.extend({
   initialize: function(options){
       this.childViews.push(options.viewName);
console.log('app2_View =>' + this.childViews);
   }
})

new App_View({viewName: 'a'});
new App2_View({viewName: 'b'});
```

This outputs:

```
app_View =>  global ,a 
app2_View => global ,a ,b
```

I don't want the same instance of childViews in all the objects that i create from Backbone.SuperView! Like you can imagine i pretend to have an array childViews in all my objects created from that class but i with different memory instances, so each view has it's own childviews.

Then i come up with the the following concept but i still think this is not the right way of doing things:

**MY SUPERVIEW CLASS**

```
;(function($, _ , Backbone) {
   'use strict';

   Backbone.SuperView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function(){
         this._views = {};
         this._listViews = [];
         this._bindedElements = [];

         _.extend(this,
            {
            _destoryAllViews: function(){
               this._removeListViews();
               this._removeViews();
               this.remove();
            },
            // destroy a view atual e as subviews e listviews
            destroy: function(options){
               options = options || {};
               var defaults = {timeout : 200};
               if (_.isEmpty(options)){
                  options = defaults;

                  setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
                     this._destoryAllViews();
                     this._cleanExternalEventBinds();
                  },this), options.timeout );
               } else {
                  this._destoryAllViews();
                  this._cleanExternalEventBinds();
               }
            },
            addListView: function(view){
               this._listViews.push(view);
            },
            // manual view cleaner
            emptyListView: function(destroy){
                this._removeListViews();
            },
            /*
               views with same keys are destroyed and then assigned
            */
            set: function(key, view, options){
               options = options || {};
               var destroy = ('destroy' in options ) ? options.destroy : true;

               if (key in this._views){
                  this._views[key].view.destroy();
               }

               this._views[key] = { 'view': view, 'destroy':  destroy };

               return view;
            },
            get: function(key){
               return this._views[key].view;
            },
            _removeViews: function(){
               _.each( this._views, function( viewSettings ){
                  if (viewSettings.destroy){
                     if (viewSettings.view.destroy){
                        viewSettings.view.destroy();
                     }
                  }
               });
            },
            _removeListViews: function(){
               _.each( this._listViews, function( view ){
                  if (view.destroy){
                     view.destroy();
                  }
               });
            },
            setEvent: function(el, eventName, callback){
               var $el = $(el),
                  callback = (_.isFunction(callback)) ? callback : this[callback];

                  $el.bind(eventName + '.' + this.cid, callback);

               this._bindedElements.push(el);
            },
            _cleanExternalEventBinds: function(){
               var _that = this;
               _.each(this._bindedElements, function(el){
                  el.off('.' + _that.cid );
               });
            }

         });

      }
   });


   //_.extend(Backbone.SuperView.prototype, )


   return Backbone;

})($, _ , Backbone);
```

**MY HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="my-btn">My-btn</a>
<div class="app-placeholder"></div>
```

**MY SCIRPT**

```
var c = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

        var C = new c([{
            name: 'Frank',
            age: 12
        },
        {
            name: 'Maria',
            age: 19
        },
        {
            name: 'Richard',
            age: 20
        }])

        var header_View = Backbone.SuperView.extend({
            events: {
                'click': 'log'
            },
            initialize: function(){
                Backbone.SuperView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
                this.$mybtn = $('.my-btn');
                this.setEvent(this.$mybtn, 'click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('hello');
                });
                this.setEvent(this.$mybtn, 'click', 'innerHello')
                // this.setEvent(this.$mybtn, 'click', 'log')
                this.$el.append('<h1>My Header</h1>')
                return this;
            },
            innerHello: function(e){
                // e.preventDefault();
                alert('hello 2');
            },
            log: function(){
                console.log(this._bindedElements);
            }
        });

        var item = Backbone.SuperView.extend({
            template: _.template('<%= age %>||<%=name%>'),
            events: {
                'click': 'log'
            },
            initialize: function(options){
                Backbone.SuperView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
                this.model = options.model;
                this.render();
            },
            render: function(){
                this.$el.html('').append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))
            },
            log: function(){
                console.log(this._bindedElements);
            }
        })

        var b = Backbone.SuperView.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                Backbone.SuperView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
                this.set('myView', new header_View());
                this.$el.html( '' ).append( this.get('myView').el );
                this.collection = C;
                this.render();
            },
            render: function(){
                this.emptyListView();
                this.addAll();
            },
            addAll: function(){
                this.collection.forEach(function(model){
                    var _item = new item({model:model});
                    this.addListView(  _item );
                    this.$el.append( _item.el );
                },this)
            }
        })

        var m = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(){

            },
        })

        var B = new b();
        $('.app-placeholder').append(B.el);
```

This doesn't feel right and i'm looking for a more solid solution.
**Do i really have to call the initializer in every single view?**

The above code works like this:

1. Run the script will render a list of 3 items and an header.
2. The header_view uses a method create by my own to bind events to DOM elements outside the view
3. It inserts the dom element into an array and later, when the element is destroy the event is also detached from that global element preventing memory and event issues.
4. In the above case only clicking in the header_view will output bounded elements from _bindedElements because iniside header_View initialize i call this.setEvent($el, 'eventName',callback)

Comment: Don't you just want to say `this.childViews = ['global'];` in your `SuperView#initialize`? Or the thing that does `this.childViews.push(...)` can create the array if it isn't there already.

Comment: I think i can set the SuperView into the initialize the problem is that I've to call Backbone.SuperView.prototype.initialize.call(this) into every other view extending from SuperView to make it work. To me It just doesn't feel right

Comment: Yeah, chaining is a bit ugly in JavaScript. But why not create the `this.childViews` array on first access? You don't really want subclasses directly messing with `childViews` anyway, right?